# Bootstrap 5 navbar does expand but doesn't close on Angular project

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Angular 12 and Bootstrap 5 to create a SPA. I created a shared navbar component. When my navbar changes to the hamburger menu button, the navbar does collapse as intended. But when i try to close it, there is no reaction. Am i missing something?

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark shadow">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/someUrl">Foo</a>
    <button 
     class="navbar-toggler" 
     type="button" 
     data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
     data-bs-target="#navbarToggleContent"
     aria-controls="navbarToggleContent" 
     aria-expanded="false" 
     aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggleContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item p-2">
         Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item p-2">
         Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item p-2">
         Item 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is fine. I forget to add the popper.js entry to my angular.json file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31695182)